# Confusion about performance optimize in tf-serving client

Tags: python, tensorflow-serving

I wrote my client following tf serving client example
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py

and single predict cost almost 600-700ms,after that i found a blog.
https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-serving-client-make-it-slimmer-and-faster-b3e5f71208fb ,and by doing it prediction cost came down to 20ms, but what i did is just replace call tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto to

```
dims = [tensor_shape_pb2.TensorShapeProto.Dim(size=1)]
tensor_shape_proto = tensor_shape_pb2.TensorShapeProto(dim=dims)
tensor_proto = tensor_pb2.TensorProto(
    dtype=types_pb2.DT_FLOAT,
    tensor_shape=tensor_shape_proto) 
for vector in vectors:
    for vector_item in vector:
        tensor_proto.float_val.append(vector_item)
request.inputs['vectors'].CopyFrom(tensor_proto)
```

i just directly import associated module like this:

```
from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2
from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2
from tensorflow.core.framework import types_pb2
```

i cannot figure out,why this is faster than example code,i even copy out make_tensor_proto impl code to my code,and it still much faster as above.They are execute same code and what make result so different?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

By replacing that code snippet you removed the tensorflow dependency from the client program. This should be the main reason why you are seeing such a reduction in inference time.